# Why does my reprojected globe visualisation not draw?

Tags: qgis

I have followed all of the instructions in *QGIS Map Design*, Graser and Peterson, Locate Press 2016, and cannot get the visual of the reprojected shapefiles clipped to Rome coordinates to draw as in Fig 12.4 p86.  Is there another step beyond applying the CRS as describe on p85 that I need to do? I have used 2.8, 2.14, 2.16 without success.

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the exact software you are using, the coordinate system(s) of the shapefiles involved, and the coordinate extent(s) of each shapefile.

Comment: which os are you using? win, mac,linux?

Answer (score 1):

I ran a Check Geometry on the world countries shapefile and found errors within it.  This appears to be the problem. Getting something approximating the correct